# How to determine server name for ms sql

Tags: windows-7, ms-sql

How do I determine the server name for ms sql server.
How do I make one, if there is no default server name. I need this so that I could use it as a database

**Update:**
I tried using the computer name + / + SQLEXPRESS but no luck..I get this:
[image]

Comment: How about `Fred`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name of your server is name of computer itself + backslash + name of instance.

If computer is called XXX then server name would be just "XXX" for default instance.
If you install SQL server express, name would be "XXX\SQLEXPRESS" since SQLEXPRESS is it's instance name.

If you want to access server on your local computer, simple dot will be enough (".") as server name.